# Azure Powershell cmdlets - Requested value 'enable' was not found

Tags: powershell, azure

First time using azure with PS.

I'm getting the following error when running a couple of basic Azure cmdlets.

**"Requested value 'enable' was not found"**

This is what i did:

1) **Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile**

2) **Import-AzurePublicSettingsFile**

3) **Get-AzureSubscripction** to check the SubscriptionID matches the one on Azure's web app

4) **Stop-azureVM -name "VMName" -ServiceName "ServiceName" -stayprovisioned** -> Got the error mentioned above

5) **Get-AzureVM** -> got the error mentioned above

I couldnt find any info except this article where people are having the same issue with no answer
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/a1ebf989-4b11-46e9-9453-62e517d72f9e/getazurevm-requested-value-enable-was-not-found?forum=windowsazuremanagement&prof=required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this @Dalmiro.  This is being worked on now.  I will post a response here as soon as I have more information.

Edit: including the link to the fix that I added in the comments below - https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/releases/tag/v0.7.3.1-February2014

Comment: See the forum post for an update from one of my colleagues saying that you can work around this issue for now by downgrading to the previous version of the powershell cmdlets - https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/releases/tag/0.7.2.1

Comment: There is a new release of the cmdlets tentatively scheduled for this week which should resolve the Get-AzureVM error.

Comment: This is now fixed - https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/releases/tag/v0.7.3.1-February2014